# How do you add query parameters in Google Optimize for a set of URLs with the same 'contains' info?

Tags: query-string, google-optimize

Trying to set up a redirect test in Google Optimize and the goal is to redirect 50% of traffic to the same URL that has ?view=Example-2022 at the end of it.

That said, we want to target a set of ~50 pages to redirect and add that query to the URL. All of the pages contain /products/socks and then have differentiating info in the URL (/products/socks-blue, /products/socks-green, etc.)

I can figure out how to get the query added to the end, but cannot figure out how to keep the base URL in place (especially across all the different variants of the page with the different color styles). [Here's how I have it set up so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt4qt.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need

[The set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPYhw.png)